# ubuntu weird refresh rates for laptop display

Tags: graphics, display, laptop, display-resolution, system-settings

I have installed ubuntu 21.04 64Bit on my Lenovo laptop.
in ubuntu's display setting, here are available refresh rates for the display:

*120.02 Hz,
119.94 Hz,
60.02 Hz,
59.96 Hz,
59.93 Hz*

Isn't it weird? Shouldn't refresh rates be Integer?

Comment: All is fine. PS refresh rates are floating numbers, but Microsoft Windows just doesn't shows that to the user, making you think it's integer.

Comment: OK, So which one should i select? 60.02 Hz, 59.96 Hz or 59.93 Hz?

Comment: In theory the voltage coming out of your power point is 110/120/220/240 (etc) Volts; in real life it's allowed to vary up/down by a %  (*according to your country rules*) meaning integers are impossible in real life (unless you *fudge* the figures as per first comment)

Comment: You should be able to use any value. As a general rule of thumb, using higher refresh rates means that your computer needs more electrical power, meaning your battery life will be shortened. So I would suggest, use 59.93Hz. If you ever encounter any display problems, just try to use another value.